# Rails: running an initializer after migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have some code which I run from an initializer and it works fine. (It saves default settings from a yaml file to the database for the [rails-settings-cache](https://github.com/huacnlee/rails-settings-cached) gem.)

But when I run this on Travis CI, since it is doing a migration from scratch, the initializer fails because the table does not exist yet.

Is there a way of running code *after* the migration but before the application starts?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So while I don't love doing this, an easy way to prevent the initializer from running during db:migrate, but running on application start or test run is to wrap it in a clause testing if the table exists.  So if you take your existing initializer code and wrap it in

```
if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? 'table_name'
   ....
end
```

where 'table_name' is the name of the missing table, then both rake db:migrate and the spec run should be able to complete successfully.

Comment: If the migration only alters a column of a table you can also use [.column_exists?](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/column_exists%3F) in order to verify changes made to a specific column